# Kivy Apk crashes with firebase admin

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, kivy, buildozer

My apk crashes everytime i run it on my phone. the logcat states the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
02-13 14:27:42.571  1453  1517 I python  :    File "/home/castor/buildozer- 
env1/DravidianUniversity/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python- 
installs/DuApp/firebase_admin/storage.py", line 23, in <module>

02-13 14:27:42.572  1453  1517 I python  :    File "/home/castor/buildozer- 
env1/DravidianUniversity/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python- 
installs/DuApp/google/cloud/storage/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>

02-13 14:27:42.573  1453  1517 I python  :    File "/home/castor/buildozer- 
env1/DravidianUniversity/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python- 
installs/DuApp/google/cloud/storage/batch.py", line 31, in <module>

02-13 14:27:42.574  1453  1517 I python  :    File "/home/castor/buildozer- 
env1/DravidianUniversity/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python- 
installs/DuApp/google/cloud/storage/_http.py", line 17, in <module>

02-13 14:27:42.574  1453  1517 I python  :  ImportError: cannot import name '_http' from 
'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

My Buildozer.spec

The _http.py file with the issue has this import for line 17

```
"""Create / interact with Google Cloud Storage connections."""

  from google.cloud import _http

  from google.cloud.storage import __version__


  class Connection(_http.JSONConnection):
        """A connection to Google Cloud Storage via the JSON REST API.
```

Buildozer requirements = python3,requests, urllib3, chardet, certifi, 
      idna, kivy==master, kivymd, google.cloud, google.cloud.storage, google.auth, cachetools, 
      pyasn1, pyasn1_modules, rsa, firebase_admin

I have tried googling a way to fix this but i have not found anything. Any assistance would be muc appreciated.